# apollo-client: makeVar / useReactiveVar can be updated from another screen?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, apollo-client

I use react-native with apollo-client3.

In my `App.js` file that starts my project, I configure if I log in go to `LoggedInNav` else `LoggedOutNav`.

```
<ApolloProvider client={client}>
  <NavigationContainer>
    <View onLayout={onLayoutRootView}></View>
    {isLoggedIn ? <LoggedInNav /> : <LoggedoutNav />}
  </NavigationContainer>
</ApolloProvider>
```

And the state whether I log in or not is tracked from `useReactiveVar`.

```
  const isLoggedIn = useReactiveVar(isLoggedInVar);
```

In my `LogIn.js` file, I do log in and if it succeeds, I update my isLoggedInVar state made from `makeVar` of **apollo/client** from false to true.

```
export const isLoggedInVar = makeVar(false);
export const tokenVar = makeVar("");

export const logUserIn = async (token) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(token));
    isLoggedInVar(true);
    tokenVar(token);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
};
```

So I update my state of makeVar in another screen, but can `App.js` listen to this update and navigate from `<LoggedInNav/>` to `<LoggedOutNav/>`?

I think App.js file is the bottom of all screens of my app, it should work.

But in my app project, I feel sometimes it might works but sometimes it throws Network error.

And in this case How can I make switch between two Navs according to Login state? Please help me.